# How to stop Visual Studio from inserting blank ineditable lines into my code

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting, removing-whitespace, codelens

Visual Studio is inserting blank ineditable lines into my code files around braces and class/function declarations:

[image: preview of the issue]

How can I remove the blank ineditable line after lines 13 and 17?

Comment: Which version of VS?

Comment: It might be CodeLens, try turning that off in settings.

Comment: @Blorgbeard It's Visual Studio 2015... EDIT: It worked: disabling CodeLens has resolved the issue: thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused in Visual Studio 2019 by CodeLens which you can disable via:

Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages->CodeLens

Comment: I wanted to add an actual answer to this question even though it was answered in comments because I spent a fair while searching for this and I hope an answer may help the question appear more prominently in searches. I think the question title could probably use some revision for keywords but AFAIK I cannot edit it.